# how to pass information from cli or server to fastcgi (php-fpm) and back again?

Tags: api, webserver, cgi, fastcgi, php

i'm trying to write a webserver. i didn't want to write a module for php, so i figured i'd pass information to php-fpm like nginx and apache does. i did some research, and setup to prototypes, and just can't get it to work.

i've set up a php service listening on port 9999 that will print_r($GLOBALS) upon each connection. i've set up nginx to pass php requests to 127.0.0.1:9999. the requests ARE being passed, but only argc (1) and argv (the path to the php service), and $_SERVER vars are populated. the $_SERVER vars has a lot of information about the current environment that the php process is acting in, but i don't see ANY information about the connected user or their request -no REMOTE_ADDR, no QUERY_STRING, no nothing...

i'm having trouble finding documentation on HOW to pass this information from the cli or from a prototype server to a fastcgi php process. i've found a list of what some of the older CGI vars are, but no information on HOW to pass them, or if any of them are outdated with fastcgi.

so, again, i'm asking HOW you pass info from your server prototype or cli to a php-fpm or fastcgi process -or, WHERE can i find proper and clear and definitive documentation on this subject? (and no, the RFC is not the answer). i've beed reading over fastcgi.com and wikipedia as well as numerous other search results...

=== update ===

i've managed to get a working fastcgi "service" up and running via a prototype in php. it listens on 9999, parses a binary fcgi request from the cli and even from nginx, it formats a binary fcgi response, sends it back over the network, and the cli displays it fine, and nginx even returns the decoded fcgi response back to the browser just like nature intended.

now, when i try to do things the other way around --write my prototype server that forms a binary fcgi packet and sends it to PHP-FPM, i get NOTHING -no error output on the cli or from the error logs (i can't ever get php-fpm to write to the error logs any way [-_-]). so, WHY wouldn't php-fpm be giving me SOME kind of response, either in error text, or in binary network packet, or ANYTHING???

so, i can SEND data from cli to to fastcgi, but i can't get any thing back, unless it's MY OWN fastcgi process (and no, i didn't take over php-fpm's port -i'm on 9999 and it's on 9000).

=============

TIA \m/(>_<)\m/

Answer (score 0):

got it.

the server passes information to the fastcgi process in the form of a network data packet. much like a dns packet, you have to use the respective binary character manipulation functions for your language to formulate the packate, including it's header and payload information, then send it across the pipe / network to the fastcgi server who will then parse the binary packet into a response. fun stuff -could have been more well documented, ahem :-\

oh, and if you prototype a listener in php, you can't access this packet via any php vars, you actually have to read the connection you're listening on (because it's a binary network packet and not plain text 'post' data sent).

i've managed to get a working fastcgi "service" up and running via a prototype in php. it listens on 9999, parses a binary fcgi request from the cli and even from nginx, it formats a binary fcgi response, sends it back over the network, and the cli displays it fine, and nginx even returns the decoded fcgi response back to the browser just like nature intended.